# Retrieve JSON Value error Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have been having a hard time retrieving eth Value from a Json url for a while now, it keeps returning the error "Undefined offset: 0" as easy as it may be to anyone giving the answer, please consider that i am a learner and upcoming. My code below

```
$ethjs = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/token_price/ethereum?contract_addresses=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&vs_currencies=eth";
$ejson = file_get_contents($ethjs);
$ejson = json_decode($ejson, true);
$one_eth = $ejson[0]->eth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from the url is something like

```
// https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/token_price/ethereum?contract_addresses=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&vs_currencies=eth
{
    "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7": {
        "eth": 0.0003859
    }
}
```

Few things from above output

- There's no [0] as you are trying to extract
- since this seems to be PHP which supports heterogeneous arrays, you need to access it via value of the `contract_address` parameter passed in url since that is the `key` in the result object.

**Putting it altogether.**

```
$ethjs = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/token_price/ethereum?contract_addresses=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&vs_currencies=eth";
$ejson = file_get_contents($ethjs);
$ejson = json_decode($ejson, true);
$one_eth = $ejson['0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7']['eth'];
echo $one_eth;
```

Comment: So in order to fetch the eth Value, how do you suggest i format the code? I am lost.

Comment: you will have to do something like `$one_eth = $ejson['0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7']['eth'];`

Comment: Now throws the error "Use of undefined constant eth - assumed 'eth' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

Comment: Equally when i do this $one_eth = $ejson['0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7'];  It echoes out "eth": 0.0003859 when what i just want is the value of eth for calculation.

Comment: @Basil Moses, Have a look at updated answer